# How to get subarray from mongo document?

Tags: mongodb, sub-array

How can I fetch a subarray from document?

Here is one of documents:

```
"director_details": {
    "0": {
        "AppointmentDate": "2010-06-02",
        "AppointmentStatus": "CURRENT",
        "AppointmentType": "SEC",
        "NumAppointments": "1",
        "Person": {
            "CountryOfResidence": [],
            "DOB": [],
            "Forename": "MARK JHONSONE",
            "Nationality": "NATIONALITY UNKNOWN",
            "PersonAddress": {
                "AddressLine": "5 PARSONS STREET",
                "Country": [],
                "County": "WEST MIDLANDS",
                "PostTown": "DUDLEY",
                "Postcode": "DY1 1JJ"
            },
            "PersonID": "CSeJxNkEELgkAQhe/9CvFerlpZsK0IFUSEUFZH2dyxlnK1XY3897mG5WV48/HezDDYf2cP4wVS8VwsTHuETANEkjMurgvzGK2HM9PwyQDfoW4qLQpV0rJSBGHr32he1gUQu6WtxIzLNJcgaAZkF+y3 [...]",
            "Surname": "WESTWOOD",
            "Title": "MR"
        }
    },
    "1": {
        "AppointmentDate": "2010-06-02",
        "AppointmentStatus": "CURRENT",
        "AppointmentType": "DIR",
        "NumAppointments": "1",
        "Occupation": "DIRECTOR",
        "Person": {
            "CountryOfResidence": "UNITED KINGDOM",
            "DOB": "1979-11-30",
            "Forename": "MARK DAVID",
            "Nationality": "BRITISH",
            "PersonAddress": {
                "AddressLine": "5 PARSONS STREET",
                "Country": [],
                "County": "WEST MIDLANDS",
                "PostTown": "DUDLEY",
                "Postcode": "DY1 1JJ"
            },
            "PersonID": "CSeJxNkN0KgkAQhe97CvG+XCt/gm0jqCAihLK6lE3HWsp129XIt881TG+GMx9nZg6DF5/sabxBKpbzuWmPkGkAj/OE8dvcPIWboW8aCzLAD6jqSoVQBS1KRRC2ukbzohJAxg1tJE6YTHMJnGZA9svD [...]",
            "Surname": "WESTWOOD",
            "Title": "MR"
        }
    }
}
```

I want to search director which forename contains "david" and surname & title are not empty.

I have a query that works pretty fine, but it also returns extra subarray which I want to remove from output.

Comment: Sorry, but this does not look like valid MongoDB document. It's just a part of it. MongoDB documents must be enclosed in brackets: `{...}`, but what you gave us is `director_details` field of some object. Also, it would be good if you provide us you working query, it will help us understand you intents.

Comment: This is a part of a mongo document .. i have working query like this  `Find(‘$and’:{  ‘director_details.Person.Forename: /david/ ’ },{‘director_details.Person.Forename:1’,’ director_details.Person.Surname:1’})`

Comment: Do you really use `‘` and `’` in your query and it works? And your `$and` looks strange. It is not a correct query!

Comment: it is just typo mistake here ... i created in msWord so it seems like this .. query is working there is no problem ..Problem is that it gives whole director_detail array instead of particular director detail which is matched ..

Comment: The problem is not only quote symbols. The whole query is incorrect. I do not beleive it was ever tested!

Answer (score 4):

Ok. Suppose your document is:

```
{
    "director_details": {
        "0": {
            "AppointmentDate": "2010-06-02",
            ...
        },
        "1": {
            "AppointmentDate": "2010-06-02",
            ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

First of all, `director_details` in you question is not an array, it's an object. And `director_details.Person.Forename: /david/` **will not match** by a couple of reasons:

1. Part of object's graph is missed, a path to `Forename` is `director_details.1.Person.Forename`.
2. Regexs in MongoDB are case sensitive by default, [you should toggle `i` flag to make it case-insensitive](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/regex/).

The correct query that will match is: `db.directors.find({"director_details.1.Person.Forename" : /DAVID/})`. With current data model it is not flexible at all, as you need to specify `0` or `1`.

Consider making `director_details` an array, like:

```
{
    "director_details": [
        {
            "AppointmentDate": "2010-06-02",
            ...
        },
        {
            "AppointmentDate": "2010-06-02",
            ...
        }
    ]
}
```

In this case the query [is very simple](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/projection/elemMatch/):

```
db.directors.find({}, {"director_details" : {$elemMatch : {"Person.Forename" : /DAVID/}}})
```

And here is the result of running it:

```
> db.directors.find({}, {"director_details" : {$elemMatch : {"Person.Forename" : /DAVID/}}}).pretty()
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("52455db9cafed39bf0dee631"),
        "director_details" : [
                {
                        "AppointmentDate" : "2010-06-02",
                        "AppointmentStatus" : "CURRENT",
                        "AppointmentType" : "DIR",
                        "NumAppointments" : "1",
                        "Occupation" : "DIRECTOR",
                        "Person" : {
                                "CountryOfResidence" : "UNITED KINGDOM",
                                "DOB" : "1979-11-30",
                                "Forename" : "MARK DAVID",
                                "Nationality" : "BRITISH",
                                "PersonAddress" : {
                                        "AddressLine" : "5 PARSONS STREET",
                                        "Country" : [ ],
                                        "County" : "WEST MIDLANDS",
                                        "PostTown" : "DUDLEY",
                                        "Postcode" : "DY1 1JJ"
                                },
                                "PersonID" : "CSeJxNkN0KgkAQhe97CvG+XCt/gm0jqCAihLK6lE3HWsp129XI",
                                "Surname" : "WESTWOOD",
                                "Title" : "MR"
                        }
                }
        ]
}
```

Comment: my Question is not how to find in sub array, my question is how to _fetch_ **sub array** with matched context ..